# Can the Services menu be edited to have submenus by editing a plist (without Automator)?

Tags: services, customization

I can edit a binary plist with Xcode or convert it to XML and edit that as text.  Never used Automator and don't want to bother **until** such time as I cannot accomplish a goal with a tool I already know.  (I'm a retired software professional, so I'm sure I can do so if it comes to that.  Meanwhile…)

GraphicConverter adds nine items to the Services menu, BBEdit adds three or more, and one is still there from an app I have deleted.  Plus they are mixed in with each other.

I'd like to make the menu easier to use bu putting all the BBEdit ones on a BBEdit submenu, similar for GraphicConverter, and remove the item that is never going to work again.

I'm almost certain there is a plist somewhere that I can edit, but I don't know where to look.  And I don't know whether the Services menu is allowed to have submenus, nor what the syntax would be.

In the Keyboard Settings, one can turn off or turn on items that are listed, but you can't add items or delete items.  And at least one of the items that I never use isn't on the list, so I can't turn it off.[image]

Comment: For Finder: Context Menu extension is another way of achieving what I think you want. https://langui.net/context-menu/

Comment: That looked like it might be worth a try, but five bucks is too much for a product with so little documentation.

Comment: It is a bit more dynamic than a file you can edit.  The various applications declare any NSServices they provide and their settings to the system (via their Info.plist), and when the settings match (and they are enabled in the preferences), the appropriate menu items are added to the Services and contextual menus.